# sails-mysql error handling : TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Tags: json, node.js, sails.js

Server: Sailsjs

Database: mysql

Node Library used: sails-mysql(0.11.5)

I am trying to insert a data in mysql from sailsjs node server.

Data to be inserted:

```
{
    "first_name": "Admin Testing",
    "last_name": "User",
    "email": "admin14@testing.com",
    "role_id": 8
}
```

Where role_id is having a foreign key relation to model role.

Here the role_id : 8 doesn't have value in role table. So while inserting, it is throwing the error. But that error we couldn't console or json.stringify since the following error occurs:

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at /var/www/aitachatbot/server/api/controllers/UserController.js:38:42
    at wrapper (/var/www/aitachatbot/server/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/lodash/index.js:3602:19)
    at applyInOriginalCtx (/var/www/aitachatbot/server/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/utils/normalize.js:421:80)
    at wrappedCallback (/var/www/aitachatbot/server/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/utils/normalize.js:331:16)
    at error (/var/www/aitachatbot/server/node_modules/switchback/lib/normalize.js:42:31)
    at _switch (/var/www/aitachatbot/server/node_modules/switchback/lib/factory.js:56:28)
    at /var/www/aitachatbot/server/node_modules/sails-hook-validation/lib/create.js:66:21
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/query/dql/create.js:223:14
    at wrapper (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/lodash/index.js:3592:19)
    at applyInOriginalCtx (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/utils/normalize.js:421:80)
    at wrappedCallback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/utils/normalize.js:335:16)
    at error (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/switchback/lib/normalize.js:42:31)
    at _switch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/switchback/lib/factory.js:56:28)
    at afterwards (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/adapter/dql.js:87:16)
    at wrapper (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/lodash/index.js:3592:19)
    at applyInOriginalCtx (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/utils/normalize.js:421:80)
    at wrappedCallback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/utils/normalize.js:335:16)
    at error (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/switchback/lib/normalize.js:42:31)
    at _switch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/switchback/lib/factory.js:56:28)
    at sendBackError (/var/www/aitachatbot/server/node_modules/sails-mysql/lib/connections/spawn.js:97:11)
    at Object.poolfully [as releaseConnection] (/var/www/aitachatbot/server/node_modules/sails-mysql/lib/connections/release.js:28:12)
    at /var/www/aitachatbot/server/node_modules/sails-mysql/lib/connections/spawn.js:90:37
    at Query._callback (/var/www/aitachatbot/server/node_modules/sails-mysql/lib/adapter.js:395:27)
    at Query.Sequence.end (/var/www/aitachatbot/server/node_modules/sails-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:96:24)
    at Query.ErrorPacket (/var/www/aitachatbot/server/node_modules/sails-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:94:8)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (/var/www/aitachatbot/server/node_modules/sails-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:280:23)
    at Parser.write (/var/www/aitachatbot/server/node_modules/sails-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:73:12)
```

How can we handle this error in sailsjs?

Answer (score 0):

In theory, you don't want these errors to ever show up in production... even if they did, the full json dump of the error object probably is not something a run-of-the-mill user wants to see.

You may also be asking about how to get full info out of this error while debugging. I guess the good news there is, you seem to already know the root cause of your error!

The error objects we have in node can have pretty different structures depending where they come from, but I have yet to encounter an error that does not have smart casting of the errors to strings. That means that even if `console.log(err)` fails, something like: `console.log('Got an error: ' + err)` will likely work, casting the error to a string.

The code could be something like this:

```
User.create({
    "first_name": "Admin Testing",
    "last_name": "User",
    "email": "admin14@testing.com",
    "role_id": 8
}).exec(function(err, createdUser) {
    if (err) {
        var readableErr = '' + err;
        console.log('Error creating user: ' + readableErr);
        // return something the client will recognize and interpret
        // you can use http error codes, or your own conventions
        return res.send({
            success: false,
            message: readableErr
        });
    }
    // do something with createdUser...
});
```